# magento delete additional images

Tags: php, magento

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail_image');
foreach ($products as $product) {
  if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
  if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
  if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
  $product->save();
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to delete additional images with this code, but I don't see a guide anywhere on the net :(  I used this code to set small, thumbnail to the base image, and now I am stuck trying to remove the duplicate additional images.

Comment: I wonder if their is a way to disable the additional images programmically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method for a C# version for doing it using soap... You may be wondering how I got to this.. Read the whole post.

```
private void RemoveImagesFromProduct()
        {
            try
            {    
                List<catalogProductImageEntity> imageList = this.mageObject.catalogProductAttributeMediaList(this.VendorProductId, null, "sku").ToList();

                // execute the soap call to remove each one
                foreach (catalogProductImageEntity catProdImg in imageList)
                {
                    this.mageObject.catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove(this.VendorProductId, catProdImg.file, "sku");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.SetProgressErrUpdate("Remove Image Handler Error");
                this.SetProgressErrUpdate(exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

After determining where the soap call points to, I find that these methods are used in Core Magento:

(app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php)

```
     public function items($productId, $store = null, $identifierType = null)
     {
         $product = $this->_initProduct($productId, $store, $identifierType);

         $gallery = $this->_getGalleryAttribute($product);

         $galleryData = $product->getData(self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE);

         if (!isset($galleryData['images']) || !is_array($galleryData['images'])) {
             return array();
         }

         $result = array();

         foreach ($galleryData['images'] as &$image) {
             $result[] = $this->_imageToArray($image, $product);
         }

         return $result;
     }

     public function remove($productId, $file, $identifierType = null)
         {
             $product = $this->_initProduct($productId, null, $identifierType);

             $gallery = $this->_getGalleryAttribute($product);

             if (!$gallery->getBackend()->getImage($product, $file)) {
                 $this->_fault('not_exists');
             }

             $gallery->getBackend()->removeImage($product, $file);

             try {
                 $product->save();
             } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                 $this->_fault('not_removed', $e->getMessage());
             }

             return true;
         }
```

At this point, I know everything that must be done to delete an image, only now a function that stands alone must be written.

```
// Set the product ID here, or load a collection and foreach it and use $product->getId()
        $prodId = 4967;
        // Reload here. Collections in magento are just unpredictable sometimes!
        $loadedProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodId);

        $attributes = $loadedProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($loadedProduct);

        if (isset($attributes['media_gallery'])) {
                // From this point forward, the gallery is represented by $attributes
                $gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];
                $galleryData = $loadedProduct->getData('media_gallery');

                if (!isset($galleryData['images']) || !is_array($galleryData['images'])) {
                        die('no images for this product');
                }

                $result = array();
                foreach ($galleryData['images'] as &$image) {
                        $data = array(
                            'file'      => $image['file'],
                            'label'     => $image['label'],
                            'position'  => $image['position'],
                            'exclude'   => $image['disabled'],
                            'url'       => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($image['file']),
                            'types'     => array()
                        );


                        foreach ($loadedProduct->getMediaAttributes() as $attribute) {
                            if ($loadedProduct->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()) == $image['file']) {
                                $data['types'][] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                                }
                        }

                        $result[] = $data;
                }

                // At this point all the media info will be displayed for the product
                // From this point forward you just need to call the same parts of the remove soap api call
                foreach ($result as $galleryResult) {
                        // if the image exists, delete it.
                        if($gallery->getBackend()->getImage($loadedProduct, $galleryResult['file'])) {
                                $gallery->getBackend()->removeImage($loadedProduct, $galleryResult['file']);
                        }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, see the part at the bottom that says "foreach ($result as $galleryResult)"? That means that it goes through each picture attached to the document and deletes it.  I expect you'll just copy and paste this, so i tested it, however if you look at my entire explanation, it outlines the fundamentals how to discover the way ANY of magento's built in soap calls work by reverse engineering them.

Also, set your username to something other than 'user822179'.